# Milliseconds to specific date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

[image]
Hello All, I have time in milliseconds and I want convert it into `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`
I have tried the following code in javascript but I failed to do it, What I get is "Thu Jul 07 2016 16:22:10 GMT+0530 (IST)" this full timestamp, Code I tried is as follows:

```
self.users[i].lastLoggedIn = (new Date(self.users[i].lastLoggedIn)).toString("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

Where am I going wrong? for reference I have attached one screen shot of the same. Thank you..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for handling dates in Javascript. It is available for browsers, server-side engines and so on.

```js
moment(self.users[i].lastLoggedIn).format("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Is that moment.js I should include in the html file first?

Comment: Yes. You can add it to your HTML as such: `<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks I will try it and let you know